# Issue while fetching data from Oracle stored procedure with cursor in ssis

Tags: sql, sql-server, oracle, ssis

I have a stored procedure in an Oracle database with a cursor output which returns a result of 14 columns and more than 100 rows.

When I execute the procedure in Oracle directly, it is working fine and returning the result in variable output pane.

How to get the same cursor output of the data in SQL Server table using SSIS?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What have you tried so far? Are you getting an error in SSIS? Do you have an Enterprise Edition of SQL Server? If you do, are you using the Attunity Oracle Connectors from Microsoft? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/integration-services/data-flow/oracle-connector?view=sql-server-ver15

Comment: Here's a blog post that describes how to call Oracle stored procs in C# using `OracleDataReader` from `System.Data.OracleClient`. You could put this code into a `Script Task`.  https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/calling-oracle-stored-procedures-from-microsoft-net/